# What's the loss that is optimized in InstructGPT RL stage?

Tags: neural-networks, optimization, reinforcement-learning, language-models

In the [InstructGPT](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2203.02155.pdf) paper they define objective of RL stage as:
[image]

They try to maximize this objective using [PPO](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.06347.pdf).

I have trouble understanding how they plug this objective into the PPO though. Do they just replace each $r_t$ in the computation of PPO advantages $\hat{A}_t$ by the value of this objective?

(which would also mean that they use $L^\text{CLIP}$ instead of $L^\text{KLPEN}$ in the final loss, otherwise KL term would be kind of duplicated, won't it?)

Answer (score 0):

InstructGPT's detailed algorithm implementation is not open sourced you may continue to search any other paper talking about its detailed PPO styled implementation. Having said that, your reference does mention that:

> Finally, since the RM loss is invariant to shifts in reward, we normalize the reward model using a bias
> so that the labeler demonstrations achieve a mean score of 0 before doing RL.

> Once again following Stiennon et al. (2020), we fine-tuned the SFT model on our environment using PPO (Schulman et al., 2017). The environment is a bandit
> environment which presents a random customer prompt and expects a response to the prompt. Given the prompt and response, it produces a reward determined by the reward model and ends the episode...  For "PPO" models, γ is set to 0. Unless otherwise specified, in this paper InstructGPT refers to the PPO-ptx models.

Since the InstructGPT PPO agent is facing a (contextual) bandit environment and it's already trained based on the supervised fine-tuning (SFT) large language GPT-3 model with the default starting policy $\pi^{SFT}$, it might be much simpler to be implemented as a PPO algo whose RL objective function in this bandit case is just your referenced equation (2) without any state transition and timesteps $T$ ($T=1$ in this case). And also because reward is normalized before training as claimed above, the advantage function $\hat A$ of any bandit arm could be simply replaced by the term $r_\theta(x,y)-\beta \log(\pi_\Phi^{RL}(y|x)/\pi^{SFT}(y|x))$ defined in your equation (2) withuot any state value baseline. Then you can run PPO with its surrogate objective function either as CLIP or KLPEN or something else.